# Grails domain class has no setter method after implement interface

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two java interface:

```
public interface ProductRevision {
    String getName();
    public ComponentRevision getTiedComponent();
}

public interface ComponentRevision {
    String getName();
}
```

And then I define two Grails domain class:

```
class GormProductRevision implements ProductRevision {
    String name
    GormComponentRevision tiedComponent
}

class GormComponentRevision implements ComponentRevision {
    String name
}
```

There is no compile error, However when I call below controller:

```
class GormProductRevisionController {
   def save() {
        GormComponentRevision gormComponentRevision = new GormComponentRevision()
        gormComponentRevision.name = 'Component'
        gormComponentRevision.save()

        GormProductRevision gormProductRevision = new GormProductRevision()
        gormProductRevision.name = 'Product'
        gormProductRevision.tiedComponent = gormComponentRevision
        gormProductRevision.save()
    }

}
```

it throws exception

```
Property 'tiedComponent' has no setter method in class 'class GormProductRevision'. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Property 'tiedComponent' has no setter method in class 'class GormProductRevision'
Line | Method
->> 2138 | setSimpleProperty in org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1957 | setNestedProperty in     ''
|   2064 | setProperty . . . in     ''
|    858 | setProperty       in org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils
|     31 | save . . . . . .  in GormProductRevisionController
|    195 | doFilter          in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|    886 | runTask           in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|    908 | run . . . . . . . in     ''
^    619 | run               in java.lang.Thread
```

Could anybody help me?

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening, but you can try `gormProductRevisionInstance.@tiedComponent = ...`, or may try to declare `tiedComponent` as a `ProductRevision`. At worst, you can declare a getter and setter.

Comment: I cannot declare tiedComponent as ComponentRevision because GORM need to recognize it as GormComponentRevision. It not works even I declare getter and setter. call @tiedComponent does work, but I don't want to use such code.

Comment: Declare a setter and `gormProductRevisionInstance.setTiedComponent(gormComponentRevisionInstance)` ?

Comment: It's strange, James Kleeh's suggestion woks on one of my testing project, but not on my real application project. The difference is, in my real application project, the java interface is declared in another java project, does it impact?

Comment: And no matter if I declare setter, once I change to   `gormProductRevisionInstance.setTiedComponent(gormComponentRevisionInstance)`  it works in my testing project, but not my real application project.@JamesKleeh

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, I don't have the reputation to 'comment' yet.)

I am seeing a strange version of this bug as well.  And I wish what I could add was concrete.  But for me, I only see this issue sometimes.  I have a domain class that implements two interfaces and all is well in testing including deploying a war on my local (Mac) machine to tomcat.

When I deploy it in ec2 (ubuntu) on tomcat, sometimes this bug occurs, sometimes not.  I thought it was that I had modified the domain object but with the datasource in 'update' (not 'create-drop') that there was some mismatch.  One time I dropped the database and let it recreate and the problem went away.  But I'm seeing the problem again and I haven't touch that domain class in a while.

I have found a workaround: take the datasource from create-drop to update, but then drop the database (using mysql or whatever your db client is), then let grails recreate the system.  Could there be a problem in create-drop?  Maybe.  Could it be my brain? Absolutely!

So I'm not sure this is the same problem, or it mine is just something different and stupid but I wanted to add that I think I'm seeing something like this as well.

BTW, this class, just to give you all the details, has a transient byte[] field for a file upload.  And that was NOT set to *bindable* until just now.  And, not to hijack the thread, but that 'transients are no longer bound by default' acts weirdly and could maybe be related to my problems.  No non-bound transients for OP's original question, right?